# Javascript - Click an unfocused link with enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeypress

The web-app I am building opens up with a splash screen with an introduction. Below that is a link to enter the webpage. I want give the user the option to press the "Enter" key or clicking the link to enter the page.

Problem that I am facing is that the link cannot be clicked unless it is focused. This code snippet works but it is really ugly and I want help to create a more modular code.

```
document.getElementById('enter_app').focus();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `document.addEventListener('keyup' ...` and check for key 13 etc.

Comment: Then remove the event :) and you are done

Comment: You can use **tabindex** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Thanks, got the code to work as I wanted now thanks to @adeneo. Greatly appreciated!

Final code:
`document.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById('enter_app').click();
    }
});`